# Cloudera Virtual Machine - Increasing Disk Size

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, cloudera, vmware-player

I have setup a virtual machine with the Cloudera distribution `CDH 5.4.0` via the VMPlayer, on windows.

When I started working with the virtual machine it was about `7GB` in size. Now it has increased to about `73GB` in size. The size I am mentioning here is the `size on disk` occupied on windows.

It creates a lot of `vmdk` files, like so:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1554776064 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s001.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2003632128 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s002.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2022244352 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s003.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1960574976 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s004.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2002780160 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s005.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1999437824 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s006.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2022309888 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s007.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2034302976 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s008.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2016215040 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s009.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2012807168 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s010.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2039087104 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s011.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2006056960 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s012.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1934229504 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s013.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1752956928 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s014.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1870921728 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s015.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2077949952 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s016.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2077884416 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s017.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2089811968 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s018.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2062548992 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s019.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2073952256 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s020.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1897857024 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s021.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1874067456 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s022.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1971912704 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s023.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2082668544 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s024.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2075656192 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s025.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1993736192 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s026.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2018181120 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s027.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1927020544 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s028.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 1448411136 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s029.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2146762752 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s030.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 2146762752 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s031.vmdk
-rw-r--r--    1 user_name  Administ 567410688 Dec 15 10:37 cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.0-0-vmware-s032.vmdk
```

Is there a way to reduce to size occupied on the disk?

Comment: It depends the use you do of your VM... If you're putting lots of data in HDFS, and/or if you're executing lots of MapReduce, Spark jobs, ... you're creating even more data and logs. You can try to change the register params in Cloudera Manager to set the level at Fatal or Error, clean all the existing and unused log, and clean your HDFS to reduce the size of your VM... If you installed several developer tools, you can try to check if there's no files to delete, too... (tar.gz, rpm, ...)

Comment: I don't have much data on HDFS nor have a executed that many Spark, MR Jobs. Is it possible for me to delete a couple of `vmdk` files without affecting  the virtual machine ?

Comment: It's very strange. can you execute a **df -h** inside your VM to know what's the available space? What you can't do is delete some vmdk. Or your VM will become inconsistent... and the only thing you'll be able to do is delete all the VM...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a docker image and Quickstart VM is via **Virtual Box**. You can use following command to increase your disk space.

1. Stop the running VM (say default)
2. Delete "default" vm.
3. Issue command, *docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "50000"

   default*      ......(50GB set here)
4. Start the default VM
5. Start the docker terminal

If #3 gives you any error saying default (or your machine) already exist, then go to the folder and delete the docker machine.

This helped me eliminate the "Free Space" critical health alert in cloudera QuickStart VM, since now it had ample space.

Comment: Thanks. But, I was not using a docker image. Is there any other workaround with the VM?